# Workaround for manually importing images' source in React

Tags: reactjs, import, loader

Is there any workaround or loader available for having to manually import images?

`<img src="../assets/img/user/user-13.jpg" alt="" />`  this sort of tags in JSX/JS files

Given that we are dealing with jsx HTML loader doesn't cut it out.

I see these sort of solutions: `<img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/images/test.jpg"}`

But in my case, I have to make such changes in 100s of files, so it would be really helpful if there are any loaders that automate such a thing.

Comment: did ever try to put it in map? if its on your asset folder you can make an array object contains image path then do REPL using map

Comment: Does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71648571/how-can-i-import-all-the-images-from-a-folder-into-an-array-with-react-builded-i

Comment: @RyanZeelie Not really I want to automate the process of having to manually import img src tags.

Comment: @AntolinBernas No, I do not want to manually maintain any maps.

Comment: This creates an object of images in the folder. Then just loop over the images and return <img> for each of them : https://stackoverflow.com/q/42118296/15474532

Answer (score 0):

```
export default function App() {

  function importAll(r) {
    let images = {};
    r.keys().map((item, index) => { images[item.replace('./', '')] = r(item); });
    return images;
  }
  
  const images = importAll(require.context('../public/assets', false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/));
  useEffect(() => {
 
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>All My images</p>
     {Object.values(images).map((img,i)=><img key={i} src={img} alt={"an alt"} />) }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Based off  stackoverflow.com/q/42118296/15474532

Comment: This doesn't work. The above code basically pulls out all the images available in the context and creates a collage. I do not want to automate imports, I want to automate having to manually write ```process.env.PUBLIC_URL ``` in  <img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/images/test.jpg"}. The template I am working in has 1000s of such imports and I am looking for loaders that could translate <img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/images/test.jpg"}  src=url to requires like what html loader does to .html file